# Change checkbox size WPF 

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

I want to make a bigger checkbox in WPF.

I've discovered that I need to do a control template, one example of which is found here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319.aspx

If I use that code the checkbox doesn't resemble the default look.  All I want to do is change the Border Width & Height attributes.

I need a control template that looks exactly like the default, from there I will just change the Width and Height.  Does anyone know where I can find one?  Or a better approach?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

How about this?

```
<CheckBox>
    <CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
    </CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
</CheckBox>
```

You can use double values for ScaleX and ScaleY if the integer values are not exactly what you want.

Comment: Elegant solution. I applied it as a global style. For those going this route, note that it scales even the content (text next to checkbox or whatever) also.

Comment: this is brilliantly simple !

Comment: You can put the text in a separate TextBlock in a StackPanel with the CheckBox if you don't want the font to double size as well. The problem at the moment is that you can control the font size, but the box size doesn't change. It really should scale by default in my opinion. You get an odd mismatch by default.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possible solution found on msdn:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/98cf8a65-f4ca-4ff5-9851-c2989b91a013

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I found is to wrap it in the ViewBox:

```
<Viewbox Height="46" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
    <CheckBox Content="Some Content"/>
</Viewbox>
```

Answer (score 3):

The default ControlTemplates can be found [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx) (see `Default WPF Themes` link).

Make sure to add the respective themes namespace to your xaml file to reference the necessary [theme controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.themes.aspx).

```xml
<theme:BulletChrome Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                    RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"
                    IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}"/>
```

I am not sure if you can just specify it generically, you might need to add references too.

The problem here is that you cannot really specify a border size either since the control encapsulates it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use visual tree of the checkbox and when the elements you want exist, change them at runtime by explicitly setting the Width and Height.  Use Peter Blois' snoop or some equivalent to see if there are named elements you can access with FindName; if not you will have to guess (e.g., some styles might have two Border elements and you must pick one) and walk the visual tree explicitly.

Keep in mind that your code should do nothing if you don't find the elements you are looking for.